# Crear instalador de aplicacion en Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#

Tengo Una aplicacion con tres proyectos (Capa Datos, Capa Negocio Capa Presentación, Proyecto principal) en C# Visual Studio 2013 y desarrolle mi base de datos en sqlserver 2012, necesito crear un instalador, con el cual pueda llevar mi aplicación a cualquier pc. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

La solucion es que realices un instalador que tenga todo empaquetado en un .exe.
Puedes utilizar [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) para crearlo, algunas opciones que permite integrar en el instalador son:

- Crear y cargar base de datos.
- Realizar instalaciones como servicios.
- Diferentes tipos de instalaciones (o los tres proyectos en uno).

Puedes obtener resultados profesionales si le dedicas tiempo, lo mejor de todo, su licencia te permite distribuir el instalador sin costo alguno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Podrias crear un Setup project por medio de la extension

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects)

con esto podras crear un proyecto de instalador para distribuir tu aplicacion.

[Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects – Hello World Installer](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125051325/http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx)

Lo que recomendaria es que la db la trates de forma separada, no la incluyas en el instalador con la aplicacion, ya que al ser Sql Server esta tiene su instalador y podrias querer generar la db por medio de script o backup lo cual complica integrar la db al instalador.

Comment: Leandro tuttini podrias profundizar un poco mas al respecto por favor, es mi primeria experiencia con este caso

Answer (score 3):

La solución que yo uso y me ha servido bastante es esta:

[InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio)

Funciona en la versión Visual Studio 2012 y todas las posteriores. Además es muy facíl de usar, esa es la parte que mas me gusta.

Answer (score 1):

igualmente puedes utilizar la opcion de "publish" y la cargas en un sitio web, te lleva control de versiones y puedes actualizar la aplicación y se actualice automaticamente en los equipos que la tienen instalada!

Aquí encontraras mas información y mas completa al respecto!

[Implementación de ClickOnce para aplicaciones de formularios Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wh45kb66(v=vs.90).aspx)