# Las opciones de crear instaladores no aparecen en Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Tengo el problema que en visual studio 2010 recién instalado no aparece como ven en la imagen de abajo: cuando se supone que  debería estar "other types" pero.no sale y los vdproj no se pueden abrir y no se como instalarlo alguien sabe algo.como puedo crear instaladores como podía antes ???

Quisiera aclarar que es una pc de windows 8 y el visual studio en windows 10 aun muestra la opcion de crear instaladores en la misma version de visual studio 2010 con el mismo dvd que se uso, es por eso que quiero saber que pasa que me falta o como lo activo.

[image]

Esta es la versión :

[image]

Comment: Las plantillas para generar instaladores no vienen incorporadas en Visual Studio, revisa esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36592/78) para obtener mas información.

Comment: En visual studio 2010 si

Comment: y las instalaste?

Comment: En el instalador no hay nada que te las diga instalar o no es todo y por lenguajes y instale todos los lenguajes igual que en la otra PC

Comment: @programmercito de hecho, en visual studio 2010 fue donde MS las eliminó, referencia (en inglés): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/somasegar/2009/12/14/building-setup-and-deployment-packages-in-vs-2010/  La alternativa que ofrecen es una version "limitada" de InstallShield. En la PC donde si te funciona probablememte ya instalaste InstallShield Limited Edition, pero eso normalmente es un download externo.

Comment: Transcribo esa página To download a copy of the InstallShield Limited Edition, click on the File | New | Project… menu within Visual Studio 2010, browse to the Other Project Types | Setup and Deployment node, and select the InstallShield 2010 node that contains a project template called “Enable InstallShield Limited Edition”.

Comment: Y de mi no aparece nada como ven arriba

Comment: En la pagina que puse aparece el enlace de lo que hay q bajar e instalar, pq no pruebas a ver si funciona? Del problema en cuestion,mi olfato me dice q es algo que te falto marcar cuando instalaste VS2010

Comment: Pero ahí hay una captura donde también está visual studio installer y el tipo de proyecto

Comment: Esto se parece un poco a tu problema: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650808/cant-enable-installshield-le-and-after-trying-to-install-it-now-wont-show-entry-in-new-project

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50419/discussion-between-yms-and-programmercito).

Answer (score 1):

este tipo de proyectos fueron descontinuados en las nuevas versiones de Visual Studio para poder crear paquetes de instalación debes usar extensiones como las siguientes:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-690586.AdvancedInstallerVisualStudio2010Extension

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deployment_technologies/2010/04/20/installshield-limited-edition-is-available-for-download-in-visual-studio-2010/

Espero te pueda ayudar

Comment: En la 2010 no y sigue sin responder ni intentar instalar ni nada el installshield

Comment: Les comento que instale en Windows 10 y ahí normal se ve por lo que ahí generaré